# Parent div not taking 100% height of container div

Tags: html, css, height, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got 4 nested `div`'s naming: `wrap` > `container` > `parentBox` > `childBox`.

Container `div` is 100% minus 70px (70px is the height of the footer (60) plus 10px = 70px).

I want the `parentBox` take the rest of the height (100%) the container `div` has left. 
And I want childBox take 100% of the parentBox `div`, minus the `header` (also inside the `parentBox` containing the word 'test') which is 40px heigh;

But the result I get is that the `parentBox` and `childBox` taking the minimum height of what the table's height is.

I came across a few posts about this here on SO, but none of them helped me with this issue.

Why is this not working?

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/29/)

EDIT: The code which I think is relevant:

```
#wrap {
      height: 100%;
      /* Negative indent footer by its height */
      margin: 0 auto -60px;
      /* Pad bottom by footer height */
      padding: 0 0 60px 0px;
    }

.parentbox {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 3px 5px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height:100%;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.childbox {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-height:100%;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: You need to put your actual code here, especially if you are linking a JSFiddle. Including pseudo code in your post in this case is against the rules, I'm pretty sure. Without code here, your question is useless if the link every disappears.

Comment: @TylerH, like that? at Cedric, what needs to be polished exactly of the code?

Comment: Yes, like that. Cedric was trying to say publish, not polish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are looking for sticky footer somehow.
You can achieve what you are looking for using display properties used by `<table>` and set them to your `<div>`.
Footer, then needs to be a child too.
The idea is : a full height table display with 3 rows with middle one taking as much room as possible .
http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/28/

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar-text ">HEADER</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="parentbox">
            <div class="header">
                 <h3>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><span style="margin-left:5px;">test</span>
        </h3>

            </div>
            <!-- header div end -->
            <div class="childbox">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Jill</td>
                        <td>Smith</td>
                        <td>50</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Eve</td>
                        <td>Jackson</td>
                        <td>94</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Jill</td>
                        <td>Smith</td>
                        <td>50</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Eve</td>
                        <td>Jackson</td>
                        <td>94</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- childbox-content div end -->
        </div>
        <!-- parentbox div end -->
    </div>
    <!-- container div end -->
    <div id="footer"><!-- back inside -->
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted credit">FOOTER</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- wrap div end -->
```

And here basicly CSS needed to dispatch table layout properties:
This will use typical behavior of table elements. If you dislike it , display : flex; instead of display:table; can be used too , but this is still much too young in CSS to be solid IE8-10 will not understand it at all
.

```
html, body, #wrap {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    /* to include borders and padding inside size calculation */
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#wrap {
    display:table;
}
.navbar, #wrap > .container, #footer {
    display:table-row;
    background:lime;
}
#wrap > .container {
    height:100%;
    background:turquoise;
}
```

This needs at least IE8 .

Beside for your question : % heights inherits values only from `height` in direct parent CSS. `min-height` is no référence for `height` nor even `min-height`.

Comment: I've been using a TB3 template to have this header - content - footer layout. The table in the content was just an example. Content can have anything inside it, `form`'s too.

Comment: i am not talking about your table ,  play with the fiddle linked and change content within the three divs set as table-row and see behavior. header and footer will shrink on their content (or height given in css), when container will take all space avalaible left in between.If container is too long, footer will be pushed down, no need to set any height, exept 100% on parents that .container needs to inherit

Answer (score 1):

Both `.parentBox` and `.childBox` only have a min-height declaration, and from what I understand, that will only work one level deep--meaning `.childBox` will never know what actual size 100% is.

Comment: So I can't use plain CSS to accomplish this?

Comment: Yeah, you need height not min-height (at least on parent box).

Comment: You can, but would need to structure it differently--if what you're trying to accomplish is a fixed size header and footer with a dynamically sized body. Is that the goal?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but try removing `height: 100%;` from `#wrap > .container`.

Comment: There is no `height: 100%;` in `#wrap > .container` only `min-height` but its a `calc()`

Comment: @Quoter in your JSFiddle, you have this block of code in your CSS: `#wrap > .container {
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 651px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-color: purple;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}`

Comment: My bad, last update didn't make it in the link. I've updated it, sorry.